# AppModelV2: how to request additional user profile data (email address, ...)

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I'm trying out the new model for unified app authentication using OpenIdConnect.

I followed the instructions at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-dotnet-web/ (sample code at https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet).

I got everything set up and I can sign in (using either Azure AD credentials or Microsoft account). By default, I get (apart from the required openid claims such as `ver`, `iss`, `aud`, `exp` etc), the following set of 'useful' (as in useful for the application developer) claims:

```
name
preferred_username
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier
http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid
```

The sample uses OpenID Connect and requests only "openid" as a scope value (cf. configuration code at https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/blob/complete/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs):

```
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // (other properties omitted for brevity)
                Scope = "openid"
            });
```

The OpenID Connect spec (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims) defines values like `profile` and `email` to request additional claims; however when I add these values the Microsoft logon page gives an error (AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope openid profile is not valid.)

How can one retrieve these additional claims? Specifically, I would like to get the user's e-mail address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only scope the v2 app model supports today for user info is openid.  Currently there isn't a way to get the user's email address.  We will add this in the future as well as a way to call the Graph API with a v2 token to get more info about the user in general.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the user's email address using this:

```
var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)this.User.Identity;
var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("preferred_username");
var claimValue = claim == null ? "" : claim.Value;
```

Now claimValue has their email address. This has worked for me with both AAD users and Microsoft Account users.

Comment: I saw that as well, but prefferred_username hardly seems a claim that is guaranteed to contain an e-mail address, does it?