# How to request email scope from AAD using Microsoft.Identity.Web

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I am trying to do something that I know how to do in .NET Framework in .NET Core but am missing a simple configuration step.

.NET Framework:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile + " " + OpenIdConnectScope.Email,
....
```

In .NET Core I am using Microsoft.Identity.Web and haven't been able to find the place to set scopes before the Azure Active Directory login request is sent. If I manually edit the URL when the login page occurs, I am able to get the email claim back by adding email to the scope in the URL query string.

This is the Startup.cs code in the new app that I think is where I need to add scope:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

As a guess, I tried adding "Scopes" to my appsettings here:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": [...]
    "Scopes": "openid profile email"
  },
```

But that doesn't seem to be attached to anything.

What worked after reading kavyasaraboju-MT's helpful answer:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Scope.Add("email");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if below references can help.

In **Startup** Config (adding email scope)

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority += "/v2.0/";
    ..
//we can add scopes this way
options.Scope.Add("openid");
     options.Scope.Add("profile");
     options.Scope.Add("email");
//
…
}
```

In `manifest` we can add optional claims (for access token or id token )

```
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [
            {
                "name": "email",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            } ],
```

[image]

Give app permissions for email ,profile and openid access in portal and grant consent.

And make sure the signin request has required scopes

> &response_type=id_token &scope=openid%20profile%20email

Please **refer** these

1. [asp.net core mvc - Azure AD v2 with Azure App Registration missing
   optional email claim in ID Token for directly assigned user - Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57558949/azure-ad-v2-with-azure-app-registration-missing-optional-email-claim-in-id-token)
2. [azure active directory - how to request additional user
   profile data (email address, ) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525995/appmodelv2-how-to-request-additional-user-profile-data-email-address)

Comment: options.Scope.Add("email"); is adding email to &scope=openid%20profile%20email but I'm still not getting the claim. I will try a few more things and see. Marking as accepted for solving scope issue.